# Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

[This is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjfDL.png) when I try to view my page that I am creating with ruby on rails. The problem is, I have already migrated my database from mysql to my ruby application. I can see it in the schema.rb folder

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string "first_name", null: false 
    t.string "last_name",  null: false
    t.string "username",   null: false
    t.string "password",   null: false
    t.string "email",      null: false
  end

end
```

here is my migration file inside my migrate folder

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

All I am trying to do is run a scaffold for that database and I keep getting the error.

Comment: How does your table have those columns (first_name, last_name, etc) without them being in the migration?

Comment: define(version: 0) means that the database has never been migrated, when you migrate it this number is updated to the migration timestamp and should look similar to this: define(version: 20140810211014). Maybe your migrations are not succeeding for any reason, try running them again and check for any errors.

Comment: Add the output from `rake db:migrate --trace` to your question, or in a gist.

Comment: I got rid of the error on the page (by the actions I took in the below answers I made) it changed the version to ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140813133141) which I guess is a good thing. But, when I did that it took out all the information about the database (t.string "first_name", null: false 
    t.string "last_name",  null: false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I think I have figured it out. I ran `rake db:migrate --trace` because of a comment above and got a huge error that started off with:

```
rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: Unknown database 'recipe_library_development'Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database
```

So, based on that I ran: `bin/rake db:create db:migrate`

I reloaded my page and the error went away.